# Mysql Stored Procedure Parameters Ordering

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hello All I have a stored procedure I am passing parameters too.

As I am passing in parameters in a different order to what is in sql it is not working. I am getting a general error. I am passing in the arguments in the correct order as per the line:

```
$stored_procedure_to_execute_with_parameters= 'Call '.$stored_procedure->name.'('.$parameter_argument_keys.')';
```

which translates into

```
Call save_user(':in_user_name', :in_user_password, :in_user_first_name') and so on.
```

My procedure in sql in the argument list is in_user_password then in_user_first_name then in_user_name.

Do arguments need to be passed in the correct order as the stored procedure itself. It is because i am creating the insert from the object which matches all parameters

```
 $results=array();

        if(!is_null($stored_procedure->getParameter()) && count($stored_procedure->getParameter()>0))
        {  
            $parameter_argument_keys= $this->parameterNamesOnly($stored_procedure->getParameter());
            $stored_procedure_to_execute_with_parameters= 'Call '.$stored_procedure->name.'('.$parameter_argument_keys.')';                     

            try{
               $connection = Yii::app()->db; 
               $command = $connection->createCommand($stored_procedure_to_execute_with_parameters);                  
               foreach ($stored_procedure->getParameter() as $parameter)
               {
                   $command->bindValue(':'.$parameter->getName(),$parameter->getValue(),$parameter->getType());
               } 
               $dataReader = $command->query();
               $dataReader->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
               $results = $dataReader->readAll();   
             }
             catch(Exception $e){
                 Yii::log('', CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR, $e->getMessage());
             }
```

Comment: yes the order of params is quite important , and has to be in the same  fashion as defined in SP.

Comment: you cant pass in by the order you specify in the calling of the stored procedure it needs to match exact the order of the sql procedure

Comment: MySQL doesn't like when you pass parameters out of order.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to pass the parameters of the stored procedure I the correct order. The sproc has no way of knowing which parameter is which other then I the ordering.

Comment: ok so passing in arguments such as has no effect Call save_user(':in_user_name', :in_user_password, :in_user_first_name') and so on.

Comment: You seem to be confusing PDO prepared statements with stored procedures. Placeholders like `:in_user_name` are part of PDO syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: i thought pdo statement would map a parameter name to the parameter in sql